In tbl_regression, is the p-value a Wald p-value but the CI is profile-likehood?
So I'm running a multiple logistic regression model. I originally calculated p-values using the summary function and confidence intervals using confint.default.
To put everything into a neat little table, I'm trying to use tbl_regression but the confidence intervals aren't matching exactly what I calculated, yet the p-values seem okay. So does tbl_regression output profile-likelihood CIs by default (i.e. using confint() rather than confint.default())?
This is the model I ran:
model <- glm(outcome ~ age+ Sex + race + country + language + 
    hiv + diabetes + contact + drug + insurance, 
    family = binomial (link = logit), data=df)

I used this code to obtain the coefficients and p-values:
summary(model)
And this code to obtain Wald confidence intervals:
confint.default(model)

Can you say whether you'd prefer to have both Wald CIs and Wald p-values (as in @Eonema's answer) or likelihood profile CIs and likelihood ratio test p-values?

Check out this example from the gtsummary websitehttps://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html#wald-ci

Yes, tbl_regression uses confint by default. From the documentation:

This function uses broom::tidy and broom.mixed::tidy to perform the
initial model formatting.

From the source of broom:::tidy.glm:
 ci <- broom_confint_terms(x, level = conf.level)

And from the source of broom:::broom_confint_terms:
ci <- suppressMessages(confint(x, ...))

However, we can write a work-around by giving tbl_regression a custom tidier function for its tidy_fun argument:
# custom wrapper from broom::tidy that substitutes the Wald CI
tidyWaldCI <- function(x, ...) {
  tidytibble <- broom::tidy(x, ...)
  tidytibble[,c("conf.int", "conf.high")] <- confint.default(x)
  return(tidytibble)
}

# call tbl_regression as you would normally, but add tidy_fun = tidyWaldCI
tbl_regression(model, tidy_fun = tidyWaldCI)


Thank you for the code! This almost worked. I tried:
tidyWaldCI <- function(x, ...) {
tidytibble <- broom::tidy(x, ...)
tidytibble[,c("conf.int", "conf.high")] <- confint.default(x)
return(tidytibble)
}
tbl_regression(model, tidy_fun = tidyWaldCI, exponentiate = TRUE)
Except it's only exponentiating the lower CI. How do I get it to exponentiate both the upper and lower CI values?

@flailing-in-r Weird... I don't know. Have you tried the solution linked in Daniel's comment, and does that work?

I figured it out! Well, I made another post here asking about it and Daniel ended up modifying the code in his website. Basically had to wrap the confint.default within an exp() function.
